# Output from an Exception class in App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging, exception

I am trying to see what exception is happening on my dev clients devserver (our servers are fine) and I have an TestException.cs class that handles the most of my exceptions from my sql statement class.

I have a method like so:

```
StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < innerException.Errors.Count; i++)
{
  errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
    "Message: " + innerException.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
    "LineNumber: " + innerException.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
    "Source: " + innerException.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
    "Procedure: " + innerException.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
}

//Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
Response.Clear();
Response.Write("FAILURE");
Response.End();
```

But the Response.XX won't compile and if I use console.writeline when it hits it on the client server, the browser gets a connection lost webpage.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No, the error isn't occurring in on my local or our servers, just the clients production server.

Comment: Just output `exception.ToString()`. Better yet, allow the exception to propagate, turn on ASP.NET Health Monitoring, and allow it to log the exception for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [**`Trace`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) class. If you link with a tracewriter in web.config [*pointing to a text file*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx) you can generate logging with `Trace.WriteLine`. Then you would just need the file uploaded to your network for reviewing.